# Scoped less files

Tags: css, less

I understand that I can scope a style tag to its parent like this:

```
<div>
  <style scoped>
  p { color: red }
  </style>
  <p>Affected</p>
</div>
<p>Unaffected</p>
```

and that I can include a CSS file in this manner:

```
<div>
  <style scoped>@import(/css/mystyle.css)</style>
  <p>Affected</p>
</div>
<p>Unaffected</p>
```

however, I use Less and would like to use the same mechanism.  I tried:

```
<div>
  <style scoped>@import(/css/mystyle.less)</style>
  <p>Affected</p>
</div>
<p>Unaffected</p>
```

how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

- You need to specify `type="text/less"` attribute for the `<style>` tag containing LESS code.
- Correct syntax for the LESS `import` statement would be: `@import "/css/mystyle.less";` (`@import(/css/mystyle.css)` is [not valid CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#at-import) too).
- `less.js` must be included *after* `style` tags of interest (e.g. if the `<style>` is in the `<body>`, `<script src="less.js" ...>` goes into the `<body>` too).

For example:

```xml
...

<body>
<span>
<style scoped type="text/less">
    @color: red;
    div {color: @color}
</style>
<div>
    foo!
</div>
</span>
<div>
    bar?
</div>

<script src="../less-1.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

...
```